# Setting the root password for a Fedora 22 cloud image

Tags: fedora, virtualbox

I am having problem logging in into a Fedora 22 virtual machine, based on a cloud F22 image. Without touching the downloaded image I could boot just not login.

I downloaded

https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/22/Cloud/i386/Images/Fedora-Cloud-Base-22-20150521.i386.raw.xz

and, following

https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/users/2013-November/442288.html

I issued

```
$ virt-sysprep -a Fedora-Cloud-Base-22-20150521.i386.raw  --root-password password:XXXX
```

on a CentOS box running

```
$ virt-sysprep --version
virt-sysprep 1.20.11
```

I created a vmdk disk image with

```
D:\iso>vboxmanage convertdd Fedora-Cloud-Base-22-20150521.i386.raw d:\VirtualBoxVirtualMachines\Fedora22\Fedora22-password.vmdk --format vmdk
Converting from raw image file="Fedora-Cloud-Base-22-20150521.i386.raw" to file="d:\VirtualBoxVirtualMachines\Fedora22\Fedora22-password.vmdk"...
Creating dynamic image with size 3221225472 bytes (3072MB)...
```

With the new Fedora22-password.vmdk I could not boot on VirtualBox, it said Boot error.

I am not sure what went wrong, either the copying to the CentOS box and back suffered some error or the virt-sysprep command had a bug. How can I check on the command line whether a raw image is bootable?

And, how could I set the password for this Fedora image, either this way or some other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that

```
--enable password
```

is essential at

https://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/users/2013-November/442288.html

```
virt-sysprep -a foo.qcow2 --enable password --root-password password:123456
```

Otherwise virt-sysprep overwrites many other things in the raw image, corrupting it so you cannot boot from it.

Omitting `--enable password` resulted in

```
$ virt-sysprep -a Fedora-Cloud-Base-22-20150521.i386.raw  --root-password password:1234
Examining the guest ...
Performing "yum-uuid" ...
Performing "utmp" ...
Performing "udev-persistent-net" ...
Performing "tmp-files" ...
Performing "sssd-db-log" ...
Performing "ssh-userdir" ...
Performing "ssh-hostkeys" ...
Performing "smolt-uuid" ...
Performing "script" ...
Performing "samba-db-log" ...
...
```

but using it the first time it was not obvious being bad.

On proper invocation it touches *only* the password part of the image:

```
$ virt-sysprep -a Fedora-Cloud-22-password.i386.raw --enable password --root-password password:XXXX
Examining the guest ...
Performing "password" ...
```

And I can now log in to the virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

The Fedora Cloud image is really meant to be run in a cloud environment, with a metadata service providing configuration data (including ssh keys for the default `fedora` account). If you want to run cloud image locally, we have a utility [testcloud](https://github.com/Rorosha/testcloud), which "spoofs" all this, so you can just do

```
 testcloud instance create <name of instance> -u <url for qcow2 image>
```

Alternately, you may want to grab one of the [Vagrant boxes](https://getfedora.org/en/cloud/download/) we build, which follow the normal vagrant conventions user and password of `vagrant` / `vagrant`. (This even comes in a VirtualBox variant.)

Comment: thanks, does this run on a Windows host?

Comment: @Gergely Good question — testcloud is in Python, so it might, but I don't know if anyone has actually tested it. It'd be pretty cool/useful if it does, though, and I'm sure any necessary patches (or simply bug reports) would be appreciated.

Comment: The Vagrant boxes, of course, will work in Windows.